# Syntax highlighting of Splunk search results is missing when grouping events via Transactions command

Tags: splunk

I use `List` view in Splunk website.

Normally in the Splunk search results, the fields are highlighted with colours(red and green). Also, if one event is coloured with white background then the next event is coloured with dark background to make it readable.

Here is the Screenshot where I blurred the data as it has company information:
[image]

But when I use `transactions` command to group events together then there is no `syntax highlighting` available even though I am using `List` view. But, the 1st **group of events** are coloured together in light background and the second **group of events** are coloured together in dark background so that works fine.

Command:-
`application_name=appname | transaction startswith="This is the start of the transaction" endswith="This is the end of the transaction"`

Screenshot:
[image]

1 transaction Splunk event taken from search result:

```
{"cf_app_id":"uuid","cf_app_name":"app-name","deployment":"cf","event_type":"LogMessage","info_splunk_index":"splunk-index","ip":"ipaddr","message_type":"OUT","msg":"2022-12-22 19:11:30.242 DEBUG [app-name,02c11142eee3be456dc30ddb1b234d5f,f20222ba46461ea9] 28 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] classname    : This is the start of the transaction","origin":"rep","source_instance":"0","source_type":"APP/PROC/WEB","timestamp":1671732690242714069}

{"cf_app_id":"uuid","cf_app_name":"app-name","deployment":"cf","event_type":"LogMessage","info_splunk_index":"splunk-index","ip":"ipaddr","message_type":"OUT","msg":"2022-12-22 19:11:30.242 DEBUG [app-name,02c11142eee3be456dc30ddb1b234d5f,f20222ba46461ea9] 28 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] classname    : app log text","origin":"rep","source_instance":"0","source_type":"APP/PROC/WEB","timestamp":1671732690243292964}

{"cf_app_id":"uuid","cf_app_name":"app-name","deployment":"cf","event_type":"LogMessage","info_splunk_index":"splunk-index","ip":"ipaddr","message_type":"OUT","msg":"2022-12-22 19:11:30.242 DEBUG [app-name,02c11142eee3be456dc30ddb1b234d5f,f20222ba46461ea9] 28 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] classname    : another app log","origin":"rep","source_instance":"0","source_type":"APP/PROC/WEB","timestamp":1671732690243306564}

{"cf_app_id":"uuid","cf_app_name":"app-name","deployment":"cf","event_type":"LogMessage","info_splunk_index":"splunk-index","ip":"ipaddr","message_type":"OUT","msg":"2022-12-22 19:11:30.242 DEBUG [app-name,02c11142eee3be456dc30ddb1b234d5f,f20222ba46461ea9] 28 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] classname    : {\"data\":{\"fields\":[{\"__typename\":\"name\",\"field\":\"value\",\"field2\":\"value2\",\"field3\":\"value 3\",\"field4\":\"value4\",\"field5\":\"value5\",\"field6\":\"value6\",\"field7\":\"value7\",\"field8\":null,\"field9\":\"value9\",\"field10\":null,\"field11\":111059.0,\"field12\":111059.0,\"field13\":null,\"field14\":\"value14\",\"field15\":\"2018-10-01\",\"field16\":null,\"field17\":false,\"field18\":{\"field19\":\"value19\",\"fieldl20\":\"value20\",\"field21\":2.6,\"field22\":\"2031-10-31\",\"field23\":\"2017-11-06\"},\"field24\":{\"field25\":\"\",\"field26\":\"\"},\"field27\":{\"field28\":{\"field29\":0.0,\"field30\":0.0,\"field31\":240.63,\"field32\":\"2022-12-31\",\"field33\":0.0,\"field34\":\"9999-10-31\"}},\"field35\":[{\"field36\":{\"field37\":\"value37\"}},{\"field38\":{\"field39\":\"value39\"}}],\"field40\":{\"__typename\":\"value40\",\"field41\":\"value41\",\"field42\":\"value 42\",\"field43\":111059.0,\"field44\":\"2031-04-01\",\"field45\":65204.67,\"field46\":null,\"field47\":\"value47\",\"field48\":\"value48\",\"field49\":null,\"field50\":\"value50\",\"field51\":null,\"field52\":null}},{\"__typename\":\"value53\",\"field54\":\"value54\",\"field55\":\"value55\",\"field56\":\"value56\",\"field57\":\"value57\",\"field58\":\"value58\",\"field59\":\"9\",\"field60\":\"value60\",\"field61\":null,\"field62\":\"value62\",\"field63\":null,\"field64\":88841.0,\"field65\":38841.0,\"field66\":null,\"field67\":\"value67\",\"field68\":\"2018-10-01\",\"field69\":null,\"field70\":false,\"field71\":{\"field72\":\"value72\",\"field73\":\"value73\",\"field74\":2.6,\"field75\":\"2031-10-31\",\"field76\":\"2017-11-06\"},\"field77\":{\"field78\":\"\",\"field79\":\"\"},\"field80\":{\"field81\":{\"field82\":0.0,\"field83\":0.0,\"field84\":84.16,\"field85\":\"2022-12-31\",\"field86\":0.0,\"field87\":\"9999-10-31\"}},\"field88\":[{\"field89\":{\"field90\":\"value90\"}},{\"field91\":{\"field92\":\"value92\"}}],\"field93\":null},{\"__typename\":\"value94\",\"field95\":\"value95\",\"field96\":\"value96\",\"field97\":\"value97\",\"field98\":\"value98\",\"field99\":\"value99\",\"field100\":\"1\",\"field101\":\"value101\",\"field102\":null,\"field103\":\"value103\",\"field104\":\"359\",\"field105\":88025.0,\"field106\":79316.87,\"field107\":\"309\",\"field108\":\"value108\",\"field109\":\"2018-10-01\",\"field110\":\"2048-09-30\",\"field111\":false,\"field112\":{\"field113\":\"value113\",\"field114\":\"value114\",\"field115\":2.35,\"field116\":\"2031-10-31\",\"field117\":\"2017-11-06\"},\"field118\":{\"field119\":\"\",\"field120\":\"\"},\"field121\":{\"field122\":{\"field123\":341.58,\"field124\":0.0,\"field125\":155.33,\"field126\":\"2022-12-31\",\"field127\":186.25,\"field128\":\"2022-12-31\"}},\"field129\":[{\"field130\":{\"field131\":\"value131\"}},{\"field132\":{\"field133\":\"value133\"}}],\"field134\":null}]}}","origin":"rep","source_instance":"0","source_type":"APP/PROC/WEB","timestamp":1671732690243306564}

{"cf_app_id":"uuid","cf_app_name":"app-name","deployment":"cf","event_type":"LogMessage","info_splunk_index":"splunk-index","ip":"ipaddr","message_type":"OUT","msg":"2022-12-22 19:11:30.242 DEBUG [app-name,02c11142eee3be456dc30ddb1b234d5f,f20222ba46461ea9] 28 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] classname    : This is the end of the transaction","origin":"rep","source_instance":"0","source_type":"APP/PROC/WEB","timestamp":1671732690870483226}
```

So even though I am using the `List` view it feels like I am seeing the `Raw` view.

Is there something I can change in the search query so that the `syntax highlighting` is applied for the search results when searching via `transactions` command?

**EDIT**:

The initial issue is resolved but that lead to another annoyance.

A `transaction` command is used to group Splunk events. In my case, each Splunk event is a JSON. So I converted all Splunk events of the transaction into JSON array and now the Syntax highlighting is applied. But the problem is that I need to manually expand each JSON using the `plus` icon. Is there an `expand all` option?
[image]

Comment: https://community.splunk.com/t5/Splunk-Search/JSON-array-in-Splunk-List-view-with-expansion-as-default/td-p/625173

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I want to preface this by saying, this wouldn't be good practice.
But regardless you could do the following.

```
| eval _raw=_raw+","
| transaction id
| eval _raw="["+rtrim(_raw,",")+"]"
```

Where the transaction line would be your own transaction command.

The reason for this behaviour, is that syntax highlights will just check that if _raw is a valid json(or xml) and highlight the _raw if it is.

when grouping events with the transaction command, the _raw becomes the multiple events appended onto one another. this does not produce a valid json therefore it won't be highlighted.

These eval function manipulate the events such that after the transaction they produce a valid json as it's a list of the individual json events.

If you are not using Json. and instead XML, you may be able to use a very similar method, but I can't tell due to the blurred pictures, looks like it is however.

Comment: I edited the question and added 1 transaction Splunk event from Splunk search results shown in screenshot. I am trying to show the field `cf_app_id` to be in red colour and value in green colour and in next line the `cf_app_name` field in red colour and value in green colour. When I appended the command you mentioned then there are zero search result

Comment: Yes, the command worked! `application_name=appname | eval _raw=_raw+"," | transaction startswith="This is the start of the transaction" endswith="This is the end of the transaction" | eval _raw="["+rtrim(_raw,",")+"]"`.  If there are 4 messages in one Splunk event then I have to manually expand each of the json message. Is there no `expand all` option?

Comment: There is another existing issue where the `msg` field is too large i.e I need to use horizontal scrollbar to read it. Is there any option to wrap it better?

Comment: Sorry I'm not aware of anyway to change the syntax highlight behaviour, you may want to contact Splunk for this

Answer (score 3):

Syntax highlighting is not standard for all Splunk events.  It is, however, done for JSON events.  The output of the `transaction` command is not valid JSON so no syntax highlighting is done.

Comment: Good to know, thanks for the information that Splunk provides syntax highlighting only for JSON events. By using Daniel Price's answer I was able to make Splunk do syntax highlighting for each of the message inside the transaction. I am converting all messages in a transaction into a JSON array to achieve this. I am yet to find out how to expand all those json results which are inside the array instead of expanding each one manually by me by pressing the `plus` icon